# Turning a letter in a sentence without the text separating into different lines

Tags: html, css

I have a sentence where I would like to turn a letter, but cannot seem to do so without the text separating into different lines. Managed to turn it with the use of a h1 and h2 but that gave me the problem of it separating into different lines I was more thinking something like this :

```css
h1 {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}
.rotate {
  -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="toptext">
  <h1> T<span class="rotate">E</span>XT TEST </h1>
</div>
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Why are you using the scale transform if you want to "turn" a letter? Wouldn't you want to rotate it?

Comment: @j08691 I think by "turn" the OP means *flip* - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/EPLjMj

Comment: @Paulie_D a 180° rotation?

Comment: Depends on what axis...it might work for some letters but not others. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KVRpOE

Comment: `transform` does not work on `display: inline` elements, which a `span` is by default.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean *flip* (around the letter's vertical axis) rather than 'rotate/turn'.

As stated, transforms do not work on inline elements so we change the `display` to `inline-block. I added a minor translation to account for the letter spacing / layout differences.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 72px;
}
.rotate {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-.2em) scale(-1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="toptext">
  <h1> T<span class="rotate">E</span>XT TEST </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use span to separate each letter and in your CSS use

```
h1 span{
display: inline-block;
transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);/* for Mozilla */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);/* for Chrome and Safari */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rotate` in your `transform`:

```
.rotate {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Adjust the rotation to your liking. I used a `display` as well, as you noticed. As [per the spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-transforms/), you can't use `transform` on `inline` elements.